# Label text is disappear on Button when button is clicked for Alloy

Tags: button, label, titanium

Developers.
Please help me.
I am developing app by using Titanium SDK.
I have met the problem that i cant fix myself.
When button is clicked, sometimes Label text have been disappear.

I will add .xml and .tss code here.
---------------.tss file------------------

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
}
"#select_language_pannel": {
    width: '84%',
    height: '45%',  
    image: '/images/select_language_pannel.png'
}

"#register_label":{
    top: '20%',
    text: 'Register New User',
    color : '#008c99',
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    font: {fontSize: '18dp', fontWeight:"bold"}
}

"#investor_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '40%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png'
}

"#investor_text": {
    text: 'INVESTOR',
    height: '100%',
    color: '#008c99',
    highlightedColor: '#FFFFFF'
}

"#company_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '60%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png'
}

"#company_text": {
    text: 'COMPANY',
    color: '#008c99',
    height: '100%',
    highlightedColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
```

-----------------.xml file---------------

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ImageView image="/images/selectlanguage_bg.png">
            <ImageView id="select_language_pannel">
                <Label id = "register_label"></Label>
                <Button id = "investor_button" onClick="onClickInvestor">
                    <Label id = "investor_text"></Label>
                </Button>
                <Button id = "company_button" onClick="onClickCompany">
                    <Label id = "company_text"></Label>
                </Button>
            </ImageView>
        </ImageView>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 0):

A button cannot have a nested label. Instead, you should use the `title` property of the button to display the text.

```
<Button id = "company_button" onClick="onClickCompany" />
```

And tss:

```
"#company_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '60%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png',
    title: "COMPANY",
    color: '#008c99'
}
```

Comment: Hello, Rene. Thank you for your help. Then still title is not showing.

Comment: how does your XML look now? Is it according to what I specified?

Comment: @RongJong have you also fixed the remainder of your xml?

Comment: Sure, i have fixed. I will be good if you help me via skype. My id is flyingdragonj. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @RongJong. I have no time for that. Instead, join http://tislack.org and ask around :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"#company_button": {
    layout: 'vertical',
    top: '60%',
    width: '64%',
    height: '13%',
    backgroundImage : '/images/btn_login_common_normal.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage: '/images/btn_login_common_pressed.png',
    title: "COMPANY",
    color: '#008c99',
    style:Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.PLAIN
}
```

> style:Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.PLAIN

Add this to button style and give title hope it will work!